# When everything is blinking, what’s still will be shown. What does this expression mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What does this expression mean?

> In a world of clutter, simplicity rules the throne. When everything is
>   blinking, what’s still will be shown.

("[Zen and the Art of Email Design](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/zen-art-email-design-cameron-conaway)," by Cameron Conaway, at LinkedIn)

I am partuculary confused by the word "blinking". 
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Blink](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blink)*** is used in the sentence with the following meaning:

> - to shine intermittently, as in signalling, or unsteadily.

The idea is that if something remains still, it is more likely to be noticed in a world where everything is set to attract attraction (by blinking for instance).

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case "blinking" is refering to sudden repeated flashes of light (like a [strobe light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strobe_light)) which cause moving objects to become less distict so only stationary (still) objects will be seen clearly.